# suggestion for creating the container

Tags: java, gwt

Please refer to the code below.
I have written one `SamplePanel` for holding the widgets.
I have not extended any `Panel` class for creating the `SamplePanel`.
When I tested it, it is working as expected.
Now my question is, can I continue creating the Panels like this? or should I `extend` from any existing GWT Panel?
Any performance or any other issue might come in future?

```
import com.google.gwt.user.client.DOM;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.Element;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.TextBox;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Widget;

public class SamplePanel {

    private Element divContainer;

    public SamplePanel() {
        divContainer = DOM.createDiv();

    }

    public void addWidgets(Widget... widgets) {

        for (Widget widget : widgets) {
            addWidget(widget);
        }
    }

    public void addWidget(Widget widget) {

        if (widget instanceof TextBox) {
            widget.getElement().addClassName("textfieldtheme");
        }
        divContainer.appendChild(widget.getElement());

    }

    public Element getContainer() {
        return divContainer;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many standard GWT widgets, including panels, have different browser-specific implementations and implement many different interfaces.

For example, this is the list of interfaces implemented by a GWT Panel:

> HasAttachHandlers, HasHandlers, EventListener, HasVisibility,
>   HasWidgets, HasWidgets.ForIsWidget, IsWidget,
>   java.lang.Iterable

LayoutPanel implements even more:

> HasAttachHandlers, HasHandlers, EventListener, AnimatedLayout,
>   HasVisibility, HasWidgets, HasWidgets.ForIsWidget, IndexedPanel,
>   IndexedPanel.ForIsWidget, IsWidget, ProvidesResize, RequiresResize,
>   java.lang.Iterable

Your panel does not implement any of them. Maybe they are not necessary for your use cases, but it's very easy to miss something when you build more complex user interfaces.

I always prefer to use a widget developed and tested in real life applications by thousands of developers even though I can easily build something similar on my own.